# Textarea that autofills as user types based on predetermined list

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms, validation

I have a textarea in an HTML form. When the user begins typing, I want to auto-populate a list of possible matches based on a pre-populated list (JSON). In the end, the user may **only** select from one of those options. A dropdown would have worked if there weren't over a thousand options. Any thoughts on how to achieve this? Or where to even start? Thanks!

[image: screenshot of a dropdown list that populates as the user types]

Comment: For a large list, you could use a virtual list in a dropdown, or show only the top 5-10 likely options.

Answer (score 0):

When you type, say "N", in a location field, it **does not** show all results starting with "N", it only shows the top few likely results.

You could follow a similar approach and populate your custom dropdown with only the first few items of your results array, or better yet, query for the first *n* results only. Top 5-8 results should be sufficient.

Comment: What would this code look like? To my understanding, you can't type into a <select> element.